# How to remove parent row and its items in array : jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Summary:**

I am creating a web page which shows results of user selections. First user select items from the given panel and clicks on add button. This creates a table row of selected items of the user(Just like adding items to the cart). User can remove items in the list when remove button is clicked. i am using parents('tr').remove()

**Issue:**

When the user clicks remove button, the row is getting deleted but the selection items a still in my array "benefits_array".

Here is jquery code:

```
.on('click','.add-benefits-items', function(e) {

    var target = $(this).siblings('.panel-body');

    var tree_benefits_text = target.find('#tree-dropdown option:selected').text();
    var display_text = target.find('#benefits-display-dropdown option:selected').text();
    var unit_text = target.find('benefitsunit.active').text();
    var dataset_text = target.find('benefitsDataset.active').text();
    var checkboxes = target.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    benefits_array.push(
    {
        Tree_Benefits : tree_benefits_text,
        Display : display_text,
        Unit : unit_text,
        Dataset: dataset_text,

    });

    $('.table-benefits').find('tbody')
        .each(function(){
            var map_elements = '<td style = "text-align:center">';
            if (display_text == 'Map') {
                map_elements += '<button data-target="#map_btn_benefits_id" type="button" class="map_btn_benefits btn btn-info active" data-toggle="modal">Map</button>';
                map_elements += '<div id="map_btn_benefits_id" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Landscape Map</h4></div>';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-body"><div id="map_id_benefits" style="width: 500px; height: 380px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div></div>';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="save-exit-benefits btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes and Close</button>';
                map_elements += '</div></div></div></div>';
                map_elements += '</td>';

            }   
            else {
                map_elements += display_text+'</td>';               
            }


        $(this).append(
        '<tr>'+
        '<td style="text-align:center"><a class="remove-row-benefits text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:center">'+tree_benefits_text+'</td>'+
        map_elements+
        '<td style="text-align:center">'+unit_text+'</td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:center">'+dataset_text+'</td>'+
        '</tr>')


     });

})

.on('click', '.remove-row-benefits', function(){
    $(this)
        .parents('tr').remove();
})
```

I am passing "benefits_array" to other template using django views.py. For this question i believe you do not need code for it. What is the logic i am missing here.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It seems you're just removing the DOM element(s). Where is the code to remove items from your array? Or are you using a model binding approach?

Comment: @sushil I'm afraid not. I believe i consumes time and sort of extra work.  I'll take suggestions. Kindly give me some logic so that i could try and let you know.

Comment: Well, $(this).parents('tr').remove(); only removes the DOM element(s). You need to somehow map each table row to an item in the array and .splice() the array to keep the DOM and it in sync.

Comment: @AlexanderMadyuskin Can you suggest some piece of code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this -

I haven't seen your table, but I am assuming each table row index corresponds to the index of that row inside `benefits_array`. *If your case is different, you may just need to subtract a fixed number from `index` below. For instance if your benefits values really start at row 3, subtract 2 from the index.*

i.e.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
</table>

benefits_array = {Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, Row 4};
```

So now, when a user goes to lets say remove Row 2 you can get it's index and then use `splice()` to remove that index from your array.

```
Click-function: {
    var row = $(this).parent('tr');
    var index = $('tr').index(row); //index starts from 0 so it's aligned with the array

    row.remove();
    benefits_array.splice(index, 1); //remove 1 item from the indexed position
}
```

Comment: thank you. This logic is very helpful. It worked with little changes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are adding the object to an array, you also need to remove that object from the array.

There are a number of ways to do this, here is one ([here is the fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/4rndfvdb/)):

```
var benefits_array = [];
var new_ary = [];
var tree_benefits_text, display_text, unit_text, dataset_text;

function removeObject(ary, name, value){
   var array = $.map(ary, function(v,i){
      return v[name] === value ? null : v;
   });
   ary.length = 0; 
   ary.push.apply(ary, array); 
}


for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    tree_benefits_text = "tbt_" + i;
    display_text = "dt_" + i;
    unit_text = "ut_" + i;
    dataset_text = "dst_" + i;

    benefits_array.push(
    {
        id: i,
        Tree_Benefits : tree_benefits_text,
        Display : display_text,
        Unit : unit_text,
        Dataset : dataset_text     
    });
}

console.log(benefits_array);

removeObject(benefits_array, "Tree_Benefits", "tbt_2");

console.log(benefits_array);
```

This will allow you to remove objects from the array based on any of the properties of the object - useful if a user removes a row, and then decides to remove another row.

Comment: Thanks for the logic.  I will generalize the code and use it